# Xbox profile question

Tags: xbox-360

I am trying to create a profile for my Xbox 360. It says I need a USB storage device. I bought one and I'm using it but it gives me the same response each time. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Xbox 360 USB flash drive FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive-faq#c1b05ec23cb14e96a47d285f0dda8b73)

> ## My USB flash drive isn’t showing up at all
>
> Have you configured your device yet?
>
> - **This is the first time I’m using the USB flash drive**
>
>   Your USB flash drive might not be in the proper format. Plug it into your PC, open up “My computer,” right-click on the USB device,
>     and select “Format.” Format the USB flash drive to FAT32. Make sure to
>     save any files before doing this, as formatting will erase all data on
>     the USB flash drive.
> - **I’ve already configured it**
>
>   Try plugging in your USB flash drive after the console starts up and see if it appears. This is a very uncommon issue, but we’re aware
>     of it and are working to correct the issue. For now, just remember to
>     plug in your USB flash drive after startup